# Show More and Show less in PHP

Tags: php, show

I really need help to show only 90 words or 400 characters of text from MySQL database. Currently my code shows everything and i was hoping to truncate and give the reader the option to see more or less text. Thank you for your help in advance ))

Comment: Have you even tried something ?

Comment: Thrre is a mysql function you can use to do just this

Comment: read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Comment: <?php

                if(strlen($query_country_province_area->get_description($properties)) > 90) {
                    $textdisplaylist = '<div>'.substr($query_country_province_area->get_description($properties),0,400).'<br><a href="#">Read More</a></div>';
                } else {
                     $textdisplaylist = '<div>'.substr($query_country_province_area->get_description($properties),0,90).'<br><a href="#">Read More</a></div>';
                }

            ?>

Answer (score -4):

```
//Check for this code .
//First decide the text limit and according to it use following code
if(strlen($text) > 90) {
    $textdisplaylist = '<div>'.substr($text,0,400).'<br><a href="#">Read More</a></div>';
} else {
     $textdisplaylist = '<div>'.substr($text,0,90).'<br><a href="#">Read More</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: I tried this and its stil showing all the text that is coming from MYSQL database!